# Is the a MVVM WPF way to implement DrawingVisual based on an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drawingvisual

My Application displays a lot of lines and polygons/paths on a canvas.
My ViewModel holds a series of `ObservableCollections` that represent different items to be drawn.

The issue I have is the application is very slow to zoom and pan.
Zoom and pan is all taken care of using an `IvalueConverter` and converts from world coordinate system to the canvas coordinate system.

For this to work, I have to `NotifyPropertyChange` all objects visible on the screen to force them to be redrawn with the latest pan and zoom values.
It works very well for a few hundred lines, but for thousands it’s very slow. And if you zoom out so all objects are visible therefore subject to `NotifyPropertyChange` it’s almost unusable  with over 10,000 lines.

I’m not using the polygons built-in features in any way as all handling, selection moving etc is taken care of in the viewmodel.
I therefore want to try and use `DrawingVisual` instead of `Shapes` as I understand they have much lower overheads but I can’t find any good MVVM examples of how to use them.
Examples I have seen show them being built in codebehind which isn’t how I think I should be using them.

Examples as follows:

```
//new DrawingVisual
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(160, 100), new System.Windows.Size(320, 80));
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue, (System.Windows.Media.Pen)null, rect);
drawingContext.Close();

//creating a Host as follows:
public MyVisualHost()
    {
    _children = new VisualCollection(this);
    _children.Add(CreateDrawingVisualRectangle());
    _children.Add(CreateDrawingVisualText());
    _children.Add(CreateDrawingVisualEllipses());

   this.MouseLeftButtonUp += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MyVisualHost_MouseLeftButtonUp);
    }
```

Unless there is a WPF way to bind to my observable collection using `DrawingVisual` I would need to create and delete drawings objects in my models. Every-time a model is updated it would then have to update my `drawingVisual`. But then I’m creating View items in model which can’t be the correct way.
Can anybody advise how I should go about implementing  `DrawingVisual` instead of `Shapes` in my MVVM application?

Here is an extract of the code I am currently using that uses `Shapes`

XAML

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="Catchments">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CatchmentPolygons" Source="{Binding Path=NetworkMain.Catchments}"></CollectionViewSource>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cad:Catchment}">
                <Polygon 
                    Stroke="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ObjectColour}, ConverterParameter=Catchment}"
                    StrokeThickness="1" 
                    Visibility="{Binding Visible, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='Hidden'}"
                    Points="{Binding Points, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource CollectionPointConverter}}">
                    <Polygon.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush 
                            Color="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ObjectColour}, ConverterParameter=Catchment}" 
                            Opacity=".25"
                            >
                            
                        </SolidColorBrush>
                    </Polygon.Fill>
                </Polygon>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CatchmentPolygons}}"></CollectionContainer>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas 
                    ClipToBounds="true">
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

My Observable Collections in my `ViewModel`:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Conduit> Conduits { get; set; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Catchment> Catchments { get; set; } = new();
```

**EDIT**

Screenshots of the Canvas with a zoomed in and zoomed out view:

Zoomed out:

[image]

The images have scaled a little bit but in reality, line thicknesses, node sizes and arrows remain constant as you zoom in and out. Only the projected coordinates of nodes change.

Zoomed in:

[image]

Comment: You could add a dependency property to your visual host and bind this one to the source property of the view model. Then the visual host can create a `DrawingVisual` per item in the source collection.

Comment: If you need strong acceleration, then asynchrony is indispensable.
You need to build a Shape or DrawingImage on Sharp in an asynchronous task, freeze and return a frozen instance from any thread.
BUT this will require a very strong re-architecture of the application.

Comment: Do your shapes change? If they don't then i would use one observablecollection as itemssource of an itemscontrol and render them in it's itemspanrl - a canvas. Then rendertransform the canvas to zoom and pan.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.
@Clemens: I will get my head round `DrawingVisual` soon so I can do some comparisons in performance.

@mm8: This sound like it's the ticket to honest. May take a fair bit of trial and error to get something that works.

Comment: @EldHasp: I haven't experimented with Threading at all yet. At the moment I'm working on items that the user will interact with, but later plan on adding the ability to load drawing files as a background which the user wont interact with. I like the idea of the user objects working on the main-thread and the background layers of separate threads. Or something like that.

Comment: @Andy: The user can add circles, lines and polygons to the canvas. Move them around, snap them to each-other and highlight them. But later I plan on adding background layers as mentioned above. I don't know if it's a valid reason, but I opted to not use RenderTransform as I wanted to keep the circle sizes, line weights, arrow sizes etc the same regardless of zoom so I would need a bunch of bindings anyway to update the sizes.

Comment: I don't follow how you can zoom in or out yet maintain the same size of things.

Comment: I've added a couple of screen grabs to explain what I mean

Comment: @Richard: Did adding a dependency property to your visual host solve your original issue?

Comment: @mm8 apologies, just seen this. Yes it did thanks. It works really well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a dependency property to your visual host and bind this one to the source property of the view model.

Then the visual host can create a `DrawingVisual` per item in the source collection